# How to make a POST request with PHP given the following HTTP + JSON

Tags: php, json, rest, post, get

I've been trying to make a POST request with PHP with something called the [WorkWave API](https://wwrm.workwave.com/api/#get-callback-url). This is the code they provide for making a POST request to set the app's callback URL:

```
POST /api/v1/callback HTTP/1.0
Accept: application/json
X-WorkWave-Key: YOUR API KEY
Host: wwrm.workwave.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "url": "https://my.server.com/new-callback",
  "signaturePassword": "g394g732vhsdfiv34",
  "test": true
}
```

I'm pretty new to processing POST and GET requests, so I don't really understand what's going on here.
What exactly is the blob of keys & values above the JSON brackets?
How do I translate what is given here to PHP and what are the most important things to understand when doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first blob are the headers that you need to send with your request. The JSON is the post body payload.

```
<?php

$url = 'https://wwrm.workwave.com/api/v1/callback';

$data = '
{
  "url": "https://my.server.com/new-callback",
  "signaturePassword": "g394g732vhsdfiv34",
  "test": true
}
';

$additional_headers = array(                                                                          
   'Accept: application/json',
   'X-WorkWave-Key: YOUR API KEY',
   'Host: wwrm.workwave.com',
   'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $additional_headers); 

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

echo  $server_output;
```

Comment: Or you could use [guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) which is a very popular and clean wrapper for the raw `curl` requests.

Comment: Ok cool, so these headers are the information that precede a request, correct? Let's say I want to make a request for an image, I'd have to specify that I want to GET a particular resource in the header right? Do queries to databases use headers as well when you want to get data, or is that completely separate from making GET / POST requests?

Comment: @10000R, Database queries are completely unrelated to HTTP requests. Every time you go to a website, you're making an HTTP request. Every request *MUST* have a header, which *must* include some mandatory fields, such as the URL. Curl builds these requirements in to the request object. `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is for additional headers, not necessarily required by the HTTP specification, but still useful to servers. It's not that these headers precede the request, they are a part of the request. Not every request needs to have a body or a data payload. You are right about the request for an image.

Comment: Awesome, that helps a lot, you explained it well. Any recommended resources for learning more about GET and POST requests?

Comment: @10000RubyPools I don't really know of any tutorials, but [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is a great start. It shouldn't take you too long to figure out how the HTTP system works, and then you'll realize it's not really that complicated. There's tons of complexities that build upon it though, like encryption with Transport Layer Security (the artist formerly known as SSL) and Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), but don't get distracted by those at first. Focus on REST, and you'll have a mostly complete picture of how the world wide web works.

Comment: Do we need 2 URLs?